# Library Manager libman throwing error while downloading font-awesome

Tags: .net-core, font-awesome, libman

I am getting below error while downloading font-awesome from the library manager libman in asp.net core project.

[LIB002]: The "font-awesome@5.15.1" library could not be resolved by the "cdnjs" provider

Command: libman install font-awesome@5.15.1 -d wwwroot/lib/font-awesome

Answer (score 0):

I remove the specific version and now its working.